# R subtracting values based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

Given a dataframe with multiple observations for years, locations (states), and months.
Such as:

```
df <- data.frame(
year = c(1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997,
         1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998),
state = c(12,  10, 12, 23, 24, 25, 33, 51, 9, 12, 10, 12, 23, 24, 25, 12),
month = c(1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1),
value = c(206466, 33474, 13670, 10597, 116669, 963675, 17834, 61573, 510190,
          315668, 37276, 30302, 60156, 122951, 1106655, 987834))
```

I would like to compute the change in the annual change in value per month for each state.

For example, for state 12, I would like to calculate the 1996 to 1997 change (109202 i.e. 315668 - 206466) and the 1997 to 1998 change (672166 i.e. 987834-315668).
Ideally, this would be calculated for each year and state to give me the state-specific annual monthly change.

I know that this can be done with multiple for loops, but I would rather avoid that.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% arrange(state, year) %>% group_by(state, year) %>% summarise(value = first(value)) %>% transmute(Diff = c(diff(value), NA)) %>% filter(!is.na(Diff)) %>% ungroup %>% right_join(df)`

Comment: Why do you leave out `13670` and `30302` for `state = 12`.  You have multiple `value` in each `state`, `month` and `year`. Can you show your complete expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'state', 'month', `arrange` by 'year' and get the difference between the current and the previous 'value' (`lag`)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
  group_by(state, month) %>%
  arrange(year, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = value - lag(value))


out %>%
   filter(state == 12)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   state, month [2]
#   year state month  value   Diff
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  1996    12     1 206466     NA
#2  1997    12     1 315668 109202
#3  1998    12     1 987834 672166
#4  1996    12     4  13670     NA
#5  1997    12     4  30302  16632
```